# Erro de conversão de string para float

Tags: python

Preciso dar entrada nessa função e neste valor para fazer o cálculo porém da este erro de conversão

```
#1ª tentativa
x0 = float(input('valor: '))
fx = float(input('função')) #Exemplo: (x0**4)^2-9*x0
print(fx)


#2ª
x0 = float(input('valor: '))
fx =(input('função') #Exemplo: (x0**4)^2-9*x0
print(float(fx))
```

> ValueError: could not convert string to float

Comment: Olá, pelo o que pude ver o código está correto para o que você descreveu que deseja fazer, ele recebe uma entrada do tipo 3.3 e converte para float. Qual a entrada que você está passando?

Comment: @DaniloCosta para a variavel x0 vou dar entrada exemplo: `2.5` e para a variavel fx vou colocar uma função exemplo `(x0**4)-9`

Comment: Não por, você não pode colocar a função assim não, ele irá interpretar como uma string mesmo. O que tu pode fazer é colocar essa expressão '(x0**4)-9' em uma def, e então, tu chama a def. Seria algo mais ou menos assim:  

def calcular (x0):
    return (x0**4)-9

x0 = float(input('valor: '))
print(float(calcular(x0)))

Comment: Olha o comentário do @AndersonCarlosWoss